# jQuery cycle png problem in ie

Tags: jquery

I know this has been covered in a variety of problems but having tried out multiple techniques I am still unable to fix my issue.

When viewing this page http://kylehouston.com/testing/png/index.html in all versions of Internet Explorer the png fading out has a black outline or background before becoming transparent again.

I have tried adding the HSLa technique http://kimili.com/journal/rgba-hsla-css-generator-for-internet-explorer/ as well as other techniques but I just can't get my head around this.

Could anyone offer some advice on how to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried it without all the ms filters?

Answer (score 0):

The ["Custom fadeIn/fadeOut" method](http://www.kevinleary.net/jquery-fadein-fadeout-problems-in-internet-explorer/)  worked for me.

Comment: Hi Samplebias,Thanks for the link il give it a look now